# How to add button in UI in marmalade tool?

Tags: c++, button, marmalade

Please anybody tell me how to add a button as they have shown example in their tool but I am not getting that as I am new to cross platform development tool but I know to develop using Eclipse? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I am a developer support engineer at Marmalade. I am not completely sure what module you are trying to use, but I recommend that you check out our documentation for IwNUI. This will allow you to add native buttons to your cross platform application:

```
http://docs.madewithmarmalade.com/display/MD/IwNUI+overview
```

Better yet, as you are new to Marmalade, why don't you try out our full game tutorial which I hope that you will find helpful.

```
http://docs.madewithmarmalade.com/display/MD/cplusplustutorial
```

Finally, if you have any other issues, you will be much more likely to get assistance at our official forums, so please feel free to visit:

```
https://devnet.madewithmarmalade.com/index.html
```

Hope this helps!